# Forcing Table Cell To Wrap Its Content With "0" Width

Tags: html, css

I am using the trick of assigning a small width to a table cell for it to wrap its content so the following works fine (I want the second and third cell to be assigned their width automatically according to their content):

```html
<table style="width:100%;">
<tr>
  <td style="width:1px;">11111111</td>
  <td>1111111111111111</td>
  <td>11111111</td>
  <td style="width:1px;">11111111</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

But in my project, I am going to animate the width of the cell content to zero so I want the cell to be also of "0" width because I have a hover styling on the cell and even 1 px will trigger this styling when the mouse hovers over it. But assigning the cells 0 width instead of 1px is totally ignored.

One solution I thought of was binding the hover styling to the div inside the td. But is there a way to make the cell width really "0"?

Answer (score 1):

try to use `table-layout:fixed` and `width:0px` on the `td`

```
<table style="width:100%;table-layout: fixed;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 0px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>1111111111111111</td>
        <td>11111111</td>
        <td style="width: 0px;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```